# Where I have to write my hook

Tags: webform-civicrm, hooks

I am new to civicrm.

I have created a module; say com.ex.myextention. and created a page its working fine.

But in my module where I have to write a hook and how to ensure the defined hook is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To implement a hook, add a function to the module's main .php file created earlier with civix generate:module" - the [developer guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/#add-a-hook-function).

However, if you've created your own page class, you may not need to use a hook at all, since you have complete control of the code.

If I haven't answered your question, please update your question with a bit more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Could you answer my new question related to this one https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19314/get-source-table-values-in-civicrm-triggerinfo