# get source table values in civicrm_triggerInfo

Tags: hooks

I have created below hook for trigger some values in my table.

Here how to get source table values that are being updated or inserted

```
function history_civicrm_triggerInfo(&$info, $tableName) {
  $sourceTable = 'civicrm_membership_log';

  $sql = "
    INSERT INTO `civicrm`.`civicrm_membershipperiod` 
(`id`, `membership_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2017-07-03', '2018-07-03');";


  $info[] = array(
      'table' => $sourceTable,
      'when' => 'AFTER',
      'event' => 'INSERT',
      'sql' => $sql,
  );
  $info[] = array(
      'table' => $sourceTable,
      'when' => 'AFTER',
      'event' => 'UPDATE',
      'sql' => $sql,
  );
}
```

Based on the source table value I have to rewrite the query `$sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this hook, but [the manual](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_trigger_info/) seems to suggest that `OLD.column_name` and `NEW.column_name` can be used to access old and new values respectively.

Comment: You are correct its working now;